# Facebook page_fan returning NULL, can't check if user likes page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a Facebook app and I need to know if the user likes a specific page or not.

I tried using:

```
$isFan = $facebook->api(array(
    "method" => "fql.query",
    "query"  => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 'SOMEPAGEID' 
                                            AND uid = me()"
));
```

It returns NULL.

I even tried the javascript SDK:

```
FB.api('/me/likes/SOMEPAGEID', function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
```

It returns nothing.

I'm asking for the following permissions:

```
$scope = "email,user_likes";
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: SELECT * was bad copy-paste... it's SELECT uid

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions look correct but I don't think that FQL queries actually support SELECT *, you have to manually list the fields

So try changing your FQL query to

```
 select page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = me() AND page_id = PAGE_ID
```

Or it might be you haven't encoded your query properly. This runs for me in the graph explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%2Bpage_id%2Bfrom%2Bpage_fan%2BWHERE%2Buid%2B%253D%2Bme%2528%2529

```
  fql?q=select+page_id+from+page_fan+WHERE+uid+%3D+me%28%29
```

so try using

```
    $isFan = $facebook->api('/fql?q='.urlencode('select page_id from page_fan WHERE uid = me() AND page_id = PAGE_ID'));
```

Comment: sorry, as I mention in the edit, the * was a last-resort panic attempt, but using uid or page_id doesn't help either :/ still returning empty array